# How to set Automatic versioning release for a Flutter package using Azure pipeline according to conventional commits

Tags: flutter, git, azure-pipelines, cicd, pub.dev

I'm currently working on setting up automatic versioning for a Flutter package using Azure Pipeline. However, I'm facing a challenge regarding how to access the pubspec.yaml file from the azure-pipelines.yml file in order to update the version attribute.

What I aim to achieve is that when a pull request is merged with the main branch, the pipeline triggers and publishes the package to pub.dev. While I've been able to accomplish these tasks, I'm struggling with implementing automatic versioning for the package based on conventional commits and semantic versioning.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: As suggested in my answer below, you can try to use a placeholder token (`{{package_version}}`) to set the value of '`version`' attribute in the `pubspec.yaml` file, and then use the Replace Tokens task to replace the placeholder token with the value of newly generated version number. I'd like to know whether you have tried as this, and whether it is working for you.

Comment: can't install the replace token extension in my  Azure DevOps organization, is there any other solution to achieve that with PowerShell to make String replace ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information about how to use command lines in PowerShell to replace the placeholder token in the `pubspec.yaml` file (see **EDIT**). check and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like as below to write the newly generated version number into the **`pubspec.yaml`** file of your Flutter project:

1. At first, ensure the **`pubspec.yaml`** file is existing in directory of your Flutter project, so that it can be checked out together with the code files.
2. Use a placeholder token (such as **`{{package_version}}`**) to set the value of '**`version`**' attribute in the **`pubspec.yaml`** file. For example.

   ```yaml
   # pubspec.yaml

   name: MyFlutterPackage
   description: My Flutter package.
   version: {{package_version}}
   . . .
   ```
3. In the pipeline, set a pipeline variable to store/pass the newly generated version number. This variable should have the same name (**`package_version`**) with the placeholder token in the **`pubspec.yaml`**.
4. In the pipeline, before the steps to build and publish the Flutter package, add a **Replace Tokens** task to replace the placeholder token with the value of the pipeline variable in the **`pubspec.yaml`**. The task is from the extension "[**Replace Tokens**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)", and you need to install this extension into your Azure DevOps organization before you can use it in pipelines.

   ```yaml
   variables:
     package_version: <new version number>

   steps:
   . . .

   - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
     displayName: 'Set version number'
     inputs:
       targetFiles: pubspec.yaml
       tokenPattern: doublebraces
       keepToken: true
       actionOnNoFiles: warn

   . . .
   ```

By this way, the pipeline will build and publish the Flutter package with the updated **`pubspec.yaml`** file which has the new version number set in it.

---

**EDIT:**

If you cannot install and use the "**Replace Tokens**" extension in your Azure DevOps organization, you can use one of the following PowerShell commands to replace the placeholder token in the **`pubspec.yaml`** file:

1. Use the PowerShell [**`-replace`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.4#replacement-operator) operator.

   ```
   ((Get-Content -Path path/to/pubspec.yaml) -replace "{{package_version}}", "$(package_version)") | Set-Content -Path path/to/pubspec.yaml
   ```

   - Use the '**`Get-Content`**' cmdlet to read the content of the **`pubspec.yaml`** file.
   - Use the operator "**`-replace "{{package_version}}", "$(package_version)"`**" to relace "**`{{package_version}}`**" with the value of the pipeline variable (**`package_version`**) in the content.
   - Use the '**`Set-Content`**' cmdlet to write the updated content into the **`pubspec.yaml`** file to override the old content.
2. Use the **`sed`** command.

   ```
   sed -i -e 's/\{\{package_version\}\}/$(package_version)/g' path/to/pubspec.yaml
   ```

---

Comment: @MohamedBENHALIMA, I have updated my above answer with more information about how to use command lines in PowerShell to replace the placeholder token in the `pubspec.yaml` file (see **EDIT**). check and try it.